# Sequence contains no elements for image processing

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, sequence, element

```
 static List<List<Point>> GetClusters(List<Point> points, double eps, int minPts)
        {
            if (points == null) return null;
            List<List<Point>> clusters = new List<List<Point>>();
            eps *= eps; // square eps
            int clusterId = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
            {
                Point p = points[i];
                if (p.ClusterId == Point.UNCLASSIFIED)
                {
                    if (ExpandCluster(points, p, clusterId, eps, minPts)) clusterId++;
                }
            }
            // sort out points into their clusters, if any
            int maxClusterId = points.OrderBy(p => p.ClusterId).Last().ClusterId;
            if (maxClusterId < 1) return clusters; // no clusters, so list is empty
            for (int i = 0; i < maxClusterId; i++) clusters.Add(new List<Point>());
            foreach (Point p in points)
            {
                if (p.ClusterId > 0) clusters[p.ClusterId - 1].Add(p);
            }
            return clusters;
        }
```

I am using method above for get cluster of image
but if I run it
**error :**  Sequence contains no elements
at :

```
int maxClusterId = points.OrderBy(p => p.ClusterId).Last().ClusterId;
```

what should I do for solve that errors?

I am trying to change from :

```
int maxClusterId = points.OrderBy(p => p.ClusterId).Last().ClusterId;
```

to :

```
int maxClusterId = points.OrderBy(p => p.ClusterId).LastOrDefault().ClusterId;
```

But the the error is :

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You say you are trying to change from...to... but they are both the same. You should probably edit that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also check `points.Count`.

```
if (points == null || points.Count==0) return null;
```